How to create consent screen and consequently scopes in JWT dynamically after a user logs in to Spring Boot OAuth2 Authorization Server?
In the implementation of Custom OAuth2 Authorization Server using Spring Boot, how is it possible to create a custom consent screen that asks for different consents based on which user has logged in? For example, consider an application that has different types of users: one having only read access (role as READER), another having read access, write access (role as ADMIN), and another having read, write, and delete access (role as SUPER_ADMIN). When a Client App takes the resource owner (user) to the authorization endpoint, the Client App does not know anything about the type of the user, so cannot decide which scopes to carry in the initial redirect request from Client App to OAuth2 Authorization Server. The Authorization Server will come to know about this, after the user has successfully logged in. So once the user has logged in, our custom authorization server has to decide the type of user (READER, ADMIM, or SUPER_ADMIN) and has to create a custom consent screen asking for relevant scopes. At this point, a user (SUPER_ADMIN) may select all scopes or one or two, and depending upon the selected scopes, an access token should be created including the scopes asked by the user.
I already tried to include custom roles using docs available at https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/guides/how-to-custom-claims-authorities.html. However, what I want is to have variable and dynamic scopes in the consent screen and consequently in the issued token.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This question is similar to: Custom OAuth2 consent flow. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
